# Visibility Control of the variables

Tags: java

```
package Array;
public class ArrayLesson1
{
    static int[] array = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("While Loop Result");
        while (i < 4) {
            int c = array[i] * array[i];
            System.out.println("Resutl = " + c);
            i++;
        }
        subclass obj = new subclass();
        obj.loopj();
        obj.loopk();
    }
}

class subclass {
    public static void loopj() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            int result = array[j] * array[j];
            System.out.println("FOR Loop J Result");
            System.out.println("Result = " + result);
        }
    }

    static void loopk() {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            int result2 = array[k] + array[k];
            System.out.println("FOR Loop K Result");
            System.out.println("Result = " + result2);
        }
    }
}
```

From the above code, I couldn't access the "array" from the class "ArrayLesson1".

Below you can find the Output:

> While Loop Result
>
> Resutl = 100
>
> Resutl = 400
>
> Resutl = 900
>
> Resutl = 1600

I am getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
compilation problems:   array cannot be resolved to a variable  array
cannot be resolved to a variable

at Array.subclass.loopj(ArrayLesson1.java:40)   
at Array.ArrayLesson1.main(ArrayLesson1.java:25)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared array in your `ArrayLesson1` class, which is not visible to your `subclass` so you are getting compilation error.

You have couple of options,

1) Create constructor in your `subclass` to accept array as an argument and create a local variable in your `subclass` and pass array from `ArrayLesson1` to your subclass like this:

```
//in subclass
private int [] array;
public subclass(int [] array) {
   this.array = array;
}
```

So call like this in your `ArrayLesson1` class like this:

```
subclass obj=new subclass(array); // Pass array like this
```

2) Modify `loopj()` and `loopk()` method to accept array as a parameter like this:

```
public static void loopj(int [] array) {
   //Codes here
//
```

and call it in your `ArrayLesson1` like this:

```
obj.loopj(array);
```

3) Or if you want to use static reference then you need to use with classname.variablename before using it, like this:

```
ArrayLesson1.array[j]
```

Let me know if this helps.